# chapter on recto, blank verso in memoir

Tags: chapters, memoir

I use the memoir class with option `openright`. In addition, I would also like to have the verso page before the chapter start blank, such that:

```
Chapter ends on recto: Next verso blank then next chapter.
Chapter ends on verso: Blank recto, blank verso, then next chapter.
```

Is there an option to achieve this automatically or do I need to create this manually for each chapter start?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is the default `memoir` behaviour. You can, of course change this:

```
% clearforchapprob.tex  SE 568204
\documentclass{memoir}
%% do not have a completely blank page before a chapter
\renewcommand{\clearforchapter}{\cleartooddpage[Non blank page]}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
Some text.
\chapter{Second}
More text.
\end{document}
```

Try the above MWE with and without the `\renewcommand{\clearforchapter}{...}`

BTW `openright` is a default `memoir` option.

Comment: To be clear: when ch 1 ends on a recto page, the following verso is blank so that ch 2 starts on recto. But when ch 1 ends on verso, I want 2 blank pages such that ch 2 starts on recto with blank verso. This is the default?

Comment: @bumblebee no, should be doable, but seems to be a waste of paper

Comment: Okay, then I am seeing thing right. Curious to learn how it can be done.

Comment: As Peter mentions you need to reprogram clearforchapter, I just don't see the point